# Creating a VBA to filter a database and split it into tables based on project ID for reporting?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, report

I have a database combining all projects in my division  which is always being updated.

The database Consists of 4 columns:

1. Date of the update
2. Project title
3. Reference
4. Status

Let's assume that we have 4 projects.

I want to a VBA that takes all of the updates for each project and have it in one table.

So eventually it will create 4 tables, each project will have its own table. Also it will have the project title as title for the table.

The new 4 tables will consist of 3 columns

1. Date
2. Reference
3. Status

<sup>(the project title will be common that's why it's removed in the new tables and it will be as a title for each table)</sup>

So the project number will be the main search criteria for the VBA.

The database info is filled up by a userform, the userform insert all the updates in that database. That's the reason I want to split the database into tables based on the project ID. Since the data is entered using a userform, the User will choose the project that he wants to update by an embedded dropdown list in the userform and then after submitting, the userform will insert the entered data in the database.

The main purpose of this request is to have a printable report combining all the projects but each project will be in separate table for an easier analysis.Sub report()

```
Sheet4.Activate


Dim project1 As String
Dim project2 As String
Dim project3 As String
Dim project4 As String
Dim project5 As String
Dim project6 As String
Dim project7 As String
Dim project8 As String
Dim project9 As String
Dim project10 As String
Dim project11 As String
Dim project12 As String
Dim project13 As String
Dim project14 As String
Dim project15 As String

Dim finalrow As Integer

Dim i As Integer

project1 = Sheet4.Range("U1").Value
project2 = Sheet4.Range("U2").Value
project3 = Sheet4.Range("U3").Value
project4 = Sheet4.Range("U4").Value
project5 = Sheet4.Range("U5").Value
project6 = Sheet4.Range("U6").Value
project7 = Sheet4.Range("U7").Value
project8 = Sheet4.Range("U8").Value
project9 = Sheet4.Range("U9").Value
project10 = Sheet4.Range("U10").Value
project11 = Sheet4.Range("U11").Value
project12 = Sheet4.Range("U12").Value
project13 = Sheet4.Range("U13").Value
project14 = Sheet4.Range("U14").Value
project15 = Sheet4.Range("U15").Value


finalrow = Sheet4.Range("A2000").End(xlUp).Row

i = 0

For i = 1 To finalrow
If Cells(i, 1) = project1 Then
Sheet7.Range("A100").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = project1


     If Cells(i, 1) = project1 Then
           Sheet4.Range(Sheet4.Cells(i, 2), Sheet4.Cells(i, 8)).Copy
            Sheet7.Range("A100").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

    End If
End If

Next i



Sheet7.Activate





End Sub
```

Comment: In the politest possible way; this site is for questions... What is yours?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't put code, so I won't put any either. 
The idea is simple:

- create a list of the projects. If you know there are 4, you can use it as a fixed parameter, but it's ugly, better count them
- count the lines you are gonna have on each project
- create an array of arrays ( redim A(1 to 4) , you can do that in VBA)
- for each project, redim a new array of correct size and fill it properly
- loop on the projects and paste the whole array in the convenient worksheet

Good luck and feel free to come back if you have a difficulty with that!

following your edition: try to use arrays:

```
Dim projectList() As String
projectList= Range(Sheet4.Range("U1"),Sheet4.Range("U1").end(xldown)).Value2
```

The number of projects will be ubound(projectlist)

About the loop: you use a loop on cells which is horribly time consuming. I suggest you use:

```
finalrow = Sheet4.Range("A2000").End(xlUp).Row
dim data()
data=range(Sheet4.Range("A1),Sheet4.Range("A" & finalrow)).value2
```

And for the output, you may use arrays and do the loop twice: once to count how many elements you'll have to store, one to store them. Trust me it will be much much faster

Good luck :-)

Comment: Thank you guys for your feedback!! Maybe I couldn't explaine my question in the right way.. The idea of generating a new tables for each project is for reporting. If I wanted to make a monthly report for all the projects I need each project to be in separate table so it will be easier for reporting. Otherwise, I would've printed the whole database but is not practical for reporting.

Comment: @Keem: this place is not "code for me". Try to do a code (for ex as I suggested) and then come back to us.

Comment: I'm sorry if you misunderstood me, I don't you guys to write the whole code for me. But I'm new in VBA and I want to know if its possible? and what are the codes that I have to use to combine the information. for what you have suggested in bullet point 2, I cannot determine how many lines I'm gonna have in each projects since the database is constantly updated. some projects will have 10 some will have 3.

Comment: If I knew how many rows ill have by each project I would've solve this issue simply by creating fixed table in the other sheet and by using VLOOKUP it will be solved.

Comment: err you can count them... Make a list of headers with no duplicates, (sorted is faster to run, slower to code), and that's it :-)

Comment: I've tried a code above and its successfully copied the updates but the problem its also copying the title the same number as the updates found.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can read here and with respect to a database perspective, it does not make much sense to create a new table for each project. This just makes it harder during coding.

You might be better off, when you have a table with your projects and another table (if necessary) with details to your projects. You can link these tables via an unique identifier. Hence, you avoid double entries in you database by storing your data in one table only. Right now, it looks like you store your data multiple times.

Comment: Thank you guys for your feedback!! Maybe I couldn't explaine my question in the right way.. The idea of generating a new tables for each project is for reporting. If I wanted to make a monthly report for all the projects I need each project to be in separate table so it will be easier for reporting. Otherwise, I would've printed the whole database but is not practical for reporting.